# Why is the use language construct in php unable to see changes in the value of a variable?

Tags: php, scope, namespaces, pass-by-reference

I have got to the chapter of [*anonymous functions*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in php manuel. In the earlier chapter two methods of passing variables to a function are explained, namely, pass by value and pass by reference. Being a javascript developer, it was very unconfortable to see that functions do not have the access to the variables defined in the parent scope. Anyways, now they have come up with a third method to pass variables to a function -- by the *use language construct*. Please consider the following example:

```
$message = "hello";
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example(); //prints hello, as expected.

$message = 'world';
$example(); //prints hello -- not world.
```

The last call to `$example` should print `"world"`, but it prints the older value of `$message`. Why is that? Instead if we had used either pass-by-value or pass-by-reference, the last function call would have printed world.

Answer (score 3):

The `use` language construct captures/copies the passed variable at the time the anonymous function is defined. If you change that variable after the function definition, the function will not notice it:

```
$foo = 'baz';

$f1 = function() use ($foo) {
    echo $foo;   
};

$foo = 'boo';

$f1(); // baz
```

However, if the variable is an object, this rule doesn't apply, as PHP passes objects by reference*, always (* read Jeto's comment below for a more accurate description):

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = 'baz';

$f2 = function() use ($foo) {
    echo $foo->bar;   
};

$foo->bar = 'boo';

$f2(); // boo
```

I think the reason PHP has `use` is for partial function application:

```
function get_multiplier($factor) {
    return function($num) use ($factor) {
        return $num * $factor;
    };
}

$multiply_by_4 = get_multiplier(4);

echo $multiply_by_4(5); // 20
```

Comment: Are there more plausible uses of `use language construct` too? Because I don't see why `use()` is designed to hold the first copy of a variable before its definition. If say `use()` was designed like a normal `function pass-by-reference`, it wouldn't change the working of your last example.

Comment: Note that "PHP passes objects by reference" can be a slightly misleading way to express things, because in PHP [passing by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#language.references.pass) implies the ability to reassign that variable itself, which will affect the original one as well. When PHP passes an object, you can *mutate* its contents (properties), however reassigning the variable will only affect the local one. You'll still have to use `&` (what PHP actually calls "pass by reference") if you wanna be able to reassign.

Comment: You are free to pass the use variable by reference like `... use (&$foo)`. This would result in a Javascript like scoping if you only consider the anonymous function's scope and its direct parent scope. If you need to access variables from 'higher' scopes, you have to pass them all the way down in PHP or use the `$GLOBALS` Superglobal in conjunction with the `global` keyword, which has it's limitations and is considered bad practice, mostly. Finally one could say, the language design doesn't allow real closures like in Javascript, because a function in PHP has no access to it's parent scope.